# How to count number of characters in a string

Tags: java, string

I am trying to count the amount of 'x' characters that are in a string, and print out the number. I end up just counting the number of characters in the string instead. Here is what I have tried:

```
int count = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < input1.length(); j++)
{
  char character = input1.charAt(j);
  count++;
}

if (indexX != -1)
  {
     System.out.println("x count: "+count);
  } // indexX = input1.indexOf('x');
```

Comment: Well you have to check if 'character' is actually x

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking if the chacter is x, and then increasing the counter.

```
if(character == 'x')
  counter++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You never check what the character is.

```
char character = input1.charAt(j);
if (character == 'x') {
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the character is 'x'. 
This is how you do it :

```
for (int j = 0; j < input1.length(); j++)
{
  char character = input1.charAt(j);
  if (character == 'x' || character == 'X') {
  count++;
 {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about comparing length of string pre and post replace, have a look at http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Count_occurrences_of_a_substring#Java

Common method that would work everywhere.